# In log4j.properties Daily appender file path with space not working

Tags: java, log4j

I am working with jar based applications in java, problem i got while starting the application,

```
`log4j.appender.Daily.File`=C:\Program Files (x86)\Bala\Logs
```

is not working when given path containing spaces in log4j.properties. but when try with without spaces it logging correctly.

please let me know if you have any doubts.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you need to provide an string of path. Use `""`

Comment: if i give string again showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change it as

```
log4j.appender.Daily.File=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Bala\\Logs
```

to escape black slashes (or)

```
log4j.appender.Daily.File=C:/Program Files (x86)/Bala/Logs
```